check if the record is the latest of a set
I am implementing refresh token rotation with reuse detection so I will have edge cases where I may receive a refresh token that is still valid (not expired) but is not the latest one issued (and so the refresh request must be rejected).
In my database I have the list of all the jwt tokens and when they have been issued.



Token
family
issued




tok1
Tok_fam
2024-10-11 08:03:45


tok2
Tok_fam
2024-10-11 08:42:07


tok3
Tok_fam
2024-10-11 09:12:45


tok4
Tok_fam
2024-10-11 09:21:34


tok5
Tok_fam
2024-10-11 10:31:58



Assuming tok4 has not expired yet (verified with the JWT validation outside mysql) it is not the latest so validation on the DB level should fail.
If I recevie tok5 it has not expired yet but is the latest issued and so the validation on DB level should be successful.
I ended up with the following query that returns 0 records in case of tok4 and 1 record in case of tok5. Is there any other way to do that that doesn't require a subquery?
SELECT token
FROM table
WHERE
    family='Tok_fam'
    AND
    token='tok4'
    AND
    issued=(SELECT max(issued) from table WHERE family='Tok_fam')


Check out the left joining self approach in the accepted answer to the duplicate question.

@Shadow I am fully aware of joins. Explicit or implicit in this case a second query is required. My question was if you can do somehow without the second query.

Again, check out the self joining approach in the accepted answer to the duplicate question. There is no subquery there.

you are not joining a table, you are joining the result of a query on a table
